# How do I catch and recover from a stack overflow in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, stack-overflow

I am writing a grading program for an assignment in which students are implementing recursive sort algorithms.  This means several students will probably turn in broken code which causes stack overflow.  I would like to somehow catch stack overflows that occur when calling the students code so I can deduct from their score and continue on to other tests.  Unfortunately, stack overflow doesn't seem to go through the standard path of other exceptions - try/catch blocks don't seem to help.  Is there a way to return execution to my code after a stack overflow has occurred?  I've looked into using threads to do this, but it just seems to come back to not being able to use try/catch.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When calling the methods of your students, you should embed the calls in try-catch blocks and catch `Exception`s as `Throwables`.

See the following code:

```
public class Test {
    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            soe();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.out.println("Caught:" + e
                    + ", everything went better than expected.");
        }
    }
    /**
     * Method producing StackOverflowError
     */
    public static void soe() {
        soe();
    }
}
```

**More info**

When catching `Throwable`s you will catch:

- Normal `Exception`s - which enforce you to use `try-catch` or `throws` (eg. `IOException`)
- `RuntimeException`s - which bubble up through methods (eg. `NullPointerException`)
- `Error`s - eg. `StackOverflowError`

See the [official Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html) on the `Throwable` object

Comment: This. Errors and Exceptions are both subclasses of Throwable, which is why Errors passes through normal Exception-catch. It is designed that way so critical failures (which is what Errors are in Java) would not be easily circumvented by programmers.

Comment: @Matyas: but at that point, can the program continue, i.e. will the stack be reset or will further attempts to do anything fail since there is no stack space available?

Comment: Yes, it can continue. The method allocations are removed from the stack as the `Throwable` "bubbles" up.
A simple proof is already in the code above, when in the `catch` block we call a new method (`println`), which gets allocated on the stack.

Answer (score 2):

You could fire off their programs using a new `Process` and then redirecting its error stream to check for stack overflow.

Comment: There's no need for that - see Matyas's answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running each program in a separate jvm.